# jQuery .click() not firing after clicking a link

Tags: jquery, url, html

I have this sample code for my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.content').click( function(){
        console.log("Test!")
     });
});
```

And I have an HTML page with X divs, preceeded by a link like so.

```
<a name="itemX"></a>
<div class="content">itemX</div>
```

On top of each div is an unordered lists with the links to all the divs in this file. When clicked on one of these links, the url changes to `"/index.html#itemX"`.

The problem is now, that when I click on the first link, it shows me the "Test!" output, but when I'm on a page with a `"#itemX"` in the url, the `click()` event doesn't fire. Is this meant to be or am I missing something? I already tried the `.on()` method aswell...

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.content').click( function(){
        console.log("Test!");//u missed semicolon
     });
});`

Comment: What's the problem? It works fine on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tBbBR/). @user2146515 missing semicolons in Javascript don't cause any trouble.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ - Does this relate to your issue? are the divs/anchor tags dynamically generated?

Comment: @JordanDoyle well jsfiddle says its an error.

Comment: Thanks guys. Got it working, seems like Firebug wasn't that cooperative...

Comment: the code in the question works fine for me... i cant understand what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebug caused this problem apparently... I uninstalled, reinstalled it and now it works fine... I have no idea how that works.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem on several browers before. Fixed it by using this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.content').bind("click", function(){
        console.log("Test!");
     });
});
```

Alternatively, perhaps binding mousedown or mouseup could do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for this! Fixed it now, was caused by Firebug :)

Comment: Note that [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) is just a syntactic sugar for [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) will run the same code.

Comment: Bind and On are the same, but click() must be different since I had click not work but bind("click", function(){}) work before. So surely something else happens with click() alone.

Answer (score -1):

u missed a semicolon on `console.log`. also add `return false` after the `console.log()` so you don't get #itemx

Comment: Thanks for the return false tip!

Comment: As I stated before, missing semi-colons don't cause any error as proven [here](http://i.imgur.com/v3H5KFw.png)